# Join pandas dataframes with different rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do my first project. I have data from 2 different months based on agent logins and their stats of the calls taken and I want to add them based on agent names

I tried joining them using

```
    aug.join(sept, how='outer', on='Agent')
```

How do I add them

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproucible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You shouldn't be providing images for the dataframes.

Comment: Your error is already describing issue, you are trying to join over different type of columns

Comment: @ÖmrümÇetin so how do i resolve it?

Comment: @ÖmrümÇetin does the concat function delete any columns? only 12 of the 17 colums showed up after concat

Comment: concat does not delete any columns

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final answer based on comments,
First you need to concat two tables, then group based on your common column, then sum it.

```py
result = pd.concat([aug,sep]).groupby(["Agent"]).sum()
```

Comment: it did not add the values. 
For example the first Agent NISSANK's Agent On Contact time has to come up as 31665+14503=46168.

The merge code is only giving 31665

Comment: @jai recheck answer.

Comment: does the concat function delete any columns? there were supposed to be 19 but only 15 showed up

Comment: Please check your table after concat, see how grouping work, this answer will get you somewhere already